# VSCode IntelliSense for NativeScript Cannot Find Module 'ui/frame'

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, nativescript

I am new to NativeScript, new to VSCode and new to TypeScript definitions and am experiencing difficulties getting setup for VSCode to perform autocompletion through IntelliSense for modules required from tns-core-modules.

The dependencies from my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "1.0.4",
    "tns-core-modules": "3.2.0"
}
```

IntelliSense for lodash works perfectly as expected. However, IntelliSense for anything from tns-core-modules does not work.

I created a project from the blank-template in NativeScript's Sidekick. After googling around I added a jsconfig.json as follows:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "checkJs": true,
        "target": "ES6",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    },
    "include": [
        "app/**/*"
    ]
}
```

CheckJS shows me this error in home-page.js

[image]

Hovering over the error it reads:

```
[js] Cannot find module 'ui/frame'.
```

I tried to do various things that I honestly, just don't understand like:

```
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/tns-core-modules/tns-core-modules.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.d.ts"/>
```

My understanding is that because "ui/frame" is not in the package.json, but nativeScript intelligently extracts the appropriate module from tns-core-modules based on what platform it's building for...

The big question is: How do you get VSCode to know about the proper mappings and make the connection between ui/frame and the appropriate "frame.d.ts".

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: 
I wanted to update any readers and let them know that I am not and do not want to write TypeScript code, but I do want VSCode to interpret the typescript definitions properly.

Comment: Would prepending tns-core-modules in front of ui/frame work?

Comment: @pkanev no unfortunately. I tried that and if my understanding of nativescript is right, it wouldn't make sense. Also if you look in frame.d.ts it actually defines the module 'ui/frame'. However, I really don't know typescript.

Comment: The runtime checks to see if `ui/frame` is a built-in (tns-core-modules) module, and then proceeds to looking through the installed node_modules. Prepending `tns-core-modules` would just resolve to node_modules/tns-core-modules, so it's not wrong.

Comment: @pkanev you are right, it doesn't break (as in the app still works on build) but it still can't find the module because there is no tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js or index.js for npm to know to import automatically. I'm getting frame.js from the package.json in ui/frame as it contains "main": "frame".  It's not going to know that it should use frame.ios.js or frame.android.js and it doesn't seem to be picking up the fact that it should use "frame.d.ts" as the types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is to use TypeScript. I couldn't get it to work without it.